# Find the minimum of two variables jointly (to select an optimal model)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, optimization, model-selection

Suppose that we have a few machine learning models and would like to perform model selection. Let's assume that I have tuples representing `(prediction_time, prediction_error)` for each model, so I'd like to find the optimal model, i.e. the one with the lowest time and error at the same time:

The solution I came up with is to solve it like an optimization problem: scale time and error vectors and then multiply their values for each model (`time * error`), that'd be the ranking metric for the model. Then just sort them. Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np

def minmax_scale (X, min, max):
    X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
    X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
    return X_scaled

# a is the original (time,error) list
a = [(2,3), (1,4), (3,2), (2,5), (8,3), (1,7), (3, 6)]
# scale time and error to the range (1,5)
time = minmax_scale(np.array([tup[0] for tup in a]), 1, 5)
error = minmax_scale(np.array([tup[1] for tup in a]), 1, 5)

# opt_a is the list of multiplied values
opt_a = [t*e for t,e in zip(time,error)]
print(opt_a)
sorted_idx = sorted(range(len(opt_a)), key=lambda k: opt_a[k])
print(sorted_idx)
```

**Questions**:

- First of all, are there any better ways to consider such a trade-off? I'd like to assume that the prediction error and prediction time are equally important, but can obviously give them some weights too
- Secondly, is the min-max scaling useful here? as shown in the example, after scaling `(8,3)` and `(3, 6)` result in the same value, because time and error have different ranges. I guess this should be okay, but still wondering if there are other common solutions / best practices.

Comment: Is `prediction time` just the time needed to estimate model by computer or time the modeled event should occur?

Comment: so, if you have a fitted (trained) model, it's the time it takes for it to make predictions for a specific test set (predict on test)